# Enable FastCGI on Apache with Puppetlabs/Apache

Tags: puppet, fastcgi, apache-2.4, vagrant, mod-fastcgi

I'm using Puppetlabs/Apache to configure Apache. In the main puppet file, I call and configure it:

```
class { '::apache': }
class { '::apache::mod::fastcgi': }
apache::vhost { "${::fqdn} non-ssl":
    servername      => $::fqdn,
    port            => '2222',
    docroot         => "/var/www/${root}",
    priority        => 10,
}
```

The `apache::mod::fastcgi` manifest works seamlessly ... with one drawback: PHP somehow still runs on `(cli)` mode:

```
vagrant@wp:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled$ php -v
PHP 5.5.12-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: May  8 2014 21:04:38)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

To confirm that, I added a `phpinfo()` call to the a `phpinfo.php` file and checked `php /path/to/phpinfo.php | less` and `Service API` still is at `cli`.

When I look into `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`, I can see `fastcgi.conf` and `fastcgi.load`. I checked the contents `sudo nano fastcgi.conf/load` - which comes from the [`fastcgi.conf.erb` template from the module](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache/blob/master/templates/mod/fastcgi.conf.erb):

```
# ===> fastcgi.conf
# The Fastcgi Apache module configuration file is being
# managed by Puppet and changes will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
  AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
  FastCgiIpcDir "/var/lib/apache2/fastcgi"
</IfModule>

# ===> fastcgi.load
adModule fastcgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_fastcgi.so
```

*Note: There is a [`vhosts.erb` template](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache/blob/master/templates/vhost.conf.erb#L64) as well, which has a [subtemplate `_fastcgi.erb`](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache/blob/master/templates/vhost/_fastcgi.erb) that builds the FastCGI block for the vhosts template.*

When I try to set it up (which puppetlabs/apache::mod::fastcgi should already have done) with `sudo a2enmod fastcgi alias`, I get the following answer (on the CLI):

```
Module fastcgi already enabled
Module alias already enabled
```

And when I check `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` contents with `sudo nano 15-default.conf`, I see the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # ...

  ## Script alias directives
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/lib/cgi-bin"
</VirtualHost>
```

I switched then to the `root`/main user with `sudo su` and checked the directory that is referenced in the `fastcgi.conf` file: `/var/lib/apache2/fastcgi`. It only has one content: An empty folder named `dynamic`. Could this be the source of the problem: An empty FastCGI lib?

I can't really get behind how FastCGI can be enabled and running, but still reading that `cli` is the mode I'm running PHP on.

#### Edit 1

I just checked if `php-fpm` is running:

```
vagrant@wp:/etc/apache2/conf.d$ ps -ef | grep php-fpm
root       935     1  0 15:58 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data   982   935  0 15:58 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data   983   935  0 15:58 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
vagrant   2760  2605  0 19:40 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto php-fpm
```

I also restarted `php5-fpm` and `apache2` services manually, but with the same result

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
sudo service apache2 restart
php -v
# still: (cli)
```

If I would know what is missing, I could manually rewrite the `httpd.conf.erb` template or just pull in those pieces that are missing and use the default puppetlabs/apache templates - as [this is an option for the module](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache#conf_template). The same goes for [`'/etc/apache2/mods-available'`](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache#mod_dir) or the [`'/etc/apache2/sites-available'` dir](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache#vhost_dir)

Answer (score 1):

First: if you you exec php -v on the shell, you'll always get the cli version. Because you're on the command line interface...

how did you install your php-fpm module? which mode did you use? (tcp or sock?)
did you already configure a vhost? 
=> not the default one - please check sites-enabled directory, there should be a file with $fqdn ($fqdn means your fully qualified domain name like example.com)

with apache 2.4 and mod_proxy_fcgi you can easily pass .php requests to your FPM pool over the vhost config:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/path/to/your/documentroot/$1
```

=> check your vhost if there is such a directive

Comment: Just to note that: I did not really install anything - it was Puppet (the provisioner I use) doing that. I linked to most of the scripts in the question.